# Android Studio Error "com.android.tools.r8.internal.r8: Dex file with version '39' cannot be used with min sdk level '26'."

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dex, android-min-sdk

I have a Android app that was working on my computer, but when I'm trying to run it using my other computer (with Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.1.1) I get the following error:

> "com.android.tools.r8.internal.r8: Dex file with version '39' cannot be used with min sdk level '26'."

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeProjectDexDebug'.
>
> - A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
>
>   - There was a failure while executing work items
>
>     - A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
>
>       - com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:

What is the easiest way to fix this?
And how can I avoid getting errors like this in the future, when moving a project from one computer to another?

Comment: Dex file version 39 was introduced with Android 10, but minSDK 26 means Android 8 which is a conflict as Andorid 8 and 9 devices don't support the used dex file format. As it happens in the merging step I would assume that one of the used libraries include the DEX code that causes the conflict.